# Find values which make binary expression evaluate to true

Tags: algorithm, parsing, expression

Given an expression like 'x < 10 and x >= 11 or x > 20', and also assuming there is already a parse tree of the expression available (e.g. [or [ [and [< [var:x]  [10] ] [>= [var:x] [11] ] ] ] [> [var:x] [20] ] ]), how can I find the range/set of x's which cause this expression to evaluate to true?

Some restrictions on the grammar are:

1. only one variable (x in the example) in an expression, so no expressions like x + 2 < y
2. only comparision operators, but could be things like empty? [string expression] in the expression
3. no arithmetic expressions or function calls - so things like x + 2 < 3, or x < someFunc() are not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like an SMT solver like Yices or Z3 would help you. They're kind of "big guns" for your problem, but should do the trick. SMT solvers are like SAT solvers on steroids, and what you have is effectively a satisfiability problem using non-boolean variables.

Answer (score 1):

A simple alternative to a SMT solver would be to:

1. Extract all the numbers used in the expression
2. Sort the list of numbers
3. For each point in the list x, evaluate the expression at x-eps,x, and x+eps(where eps is a small number)

The value of the expression can only change at these points, and as they are in sorted order you can simply join the results together to find the complete list of allowed values for x.